# Can't echo data from mysqli query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I got this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM track 
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.trackid = track.trackid AND likes.userid='$userid' 
WHERE likes.userid is null ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
```

And now I can't echo `<?php echo $row['trackid']; ?>` from the "track" table (there is however a row with the same name in the "likes" table, I suggest this could be an issue but I can't figure it out).

I hope u all get the issue I'm having, otherwise i will try to explain better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use explicit column name and alias for get the result in different colname

```
SELECT likes.trackid like_trackid, track.trackid track_trackid
 FROM track 
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.trackid = track.trackid AND likes.userid='$userid' 
WHERE likes.userid is null 
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;


<?php echo $row['like_trackid']; ?>

<?php echo $row['track_trackid']; ?>
```

or you could try using a select * for one table and the explicit column for the second  mathcing column

```
SELECT likes.*, track.trackid track_trackid
 FROM track 
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.trackid = track.trackid AND likes.userid='$userid' 
WHERE likes.userid is null 
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;

<?php echo $row['trackid']; ?>  // this came from  the select *

<?php echo $row['track_trackid']; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this almost fixed the issue, as u saw in my question I would like to be able to echo everything (*) from the row, is this possible?